# Display flex with Safari issue

Tags: html, css, safari, flexbox

Little problem here.

I have an issue with Safari and `flex`.

Here is what I want to achieve with chrome and the result with Safari 
[Result with chrome, firefox, ...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zDanj.png) and
[with Safari](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4MPv.png).

And the code:

```
<style>
  #div1{background:black;width:250px;height:600px;display:flex;flex-direction:column;padding-bottom:5px}
  #div2{background:pink;color:#FFF;width:240px;height:200px}
  #div3{background:blue;color:#FFF;width:240px;height:100%;position:relative}
</style>

<div id="div1">
  <div id="div2">test</div>
  <div id="div3">test2</div>
</div>
```

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: And the Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/g210444r/5/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flex items overflowing container in Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46202929/flex-items-overflowing-container-in-safari)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution. Here is what I did:

```
#div3{
  background:blue;
  color:#FFF;
  width:240px;
  height:100%;
  flex:1 1 100%;
  height:auto;
}
```