# Flex items overflowing container in Safari

Tags: html, css, safari, flexbox

For some reason, flex items are not staying inside the container in Safari.

Here's what the layout looks like in Chrome and Firefox:

[image]

Here's what it looks like in Safari:

[image]

Here's my code:

```css
#div1 {
  background: black;
  width: 250px;
  height: 600px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding-bottom: 5px
}

#div2 {
  background: pink;
  color: #FFF;
  width: 240px;
  height: 200px
}

#div3 {
  background: blue;
  color: #FFF;
  width: 240px;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">
  <div id="div2">test</div>
  <div id="div3">test2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sometimes people post good questions. The community delivers answers. Then the asker deletes the post! I've reproduced the question (with some edits for clarity) and added my original answer. Anybody else who worked on the original question, feel free to add your answer here.

Comment: I follow you in css tag and when i look at your profile, i asked my self, why this man usually post a question and answer himself. Now i know the answer. LOL. Keep it up, man!

Answer (score 4):

### The Problem

You have a container with `height: 600px`.

This container has two children:

- One child has `height: 200px`.
- The other child has `height: 100%`.

Since percentage heights are based on the height of the parent, you are setting the height of the second child to equal the full height of the container.

> [**10.5 Content height: the `height` property**](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visudet.html#the-height-property)
>
> **percentage**
>
> Specifies a percentage height. The percentage is calculated with respect to the height of the generated box's containing block.

As a result, an overflow occurs:

```
(200px + 600px) > 600px
```

**Except** that in a flex container, an initial setting is [**`flex-shrink: 1`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-shrink). This means that flex items can shrink in order to fit inside the container. Chrome and Firefox apply this setting correctly, allowing the element with `height: 100%` to shrink to fit. Safari, apparently, has a different interpretation.

---

### Solutions

You could use [**`calc()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) to solve the problem:

```
#div3 {
  height: calc(100% - 200px);
}
```

```css
#div1 {
  background: black;
  width: 250px;
  height: 600px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding-bottom: 5px
}

#div2 {
  background: pink;
  color: #FFF;
  width: 240px;
  height: 200px
}

#div3 {
  background: blue;
  color: #FFF;
  width: 240px;
  height: calc(100% - 200px);
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">
  <div id="div2">test</div>
  <div id="div3">test2</div>
</div>
```

However, since you're already working in a column-direction flex container, you can use `flex` to make the second child consume remaining space:

```
#div3 {
  flex: 1;
}
```

This means: *Any space not used up by other siblings will be consumed by this child.*

```css
#div1 {
  background: black;
  width: 250px;
  height: 600px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding-bottom: 5px
}

#div2 {
  background: pink;
  color: #FFF;
  width: 240px;
  height: 200px
}

#div3 {
  background: blue;
  color: #FFF;
  width: 240px;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">
  <div id="div2">test</div>
  <div id="div3">test2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You are actually making the world a better place :P